# How to rename files with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help correcting this error

```
import os

def rename_file () :
    # 1. get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(r"E:\Downloads\prank\prank")
    #print (file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print ("current working directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir (r"E:\Downloads\prank\prank")

    # 2. for each file, rename filename
    for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)     
rename_file()
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the error, and it's not clear what you want to rename the files to. Maybe you want to concatenate '0123456789' to the file name? I'll do a date since it's more meaningful. So this is as good as it will get based on what you provided. In this scenario there is a directory with 5 files in it and we'll tack on the date to each file. The directory where the files are is called 'source-files'. And the source code for the script is in the same parent directory as 'source_files'. This script changes the file names in the directory that they reside in. Of course you can save them in a different directory if you want to. The file names are: file001.txt, file002.txt, file003.txt, file004.txt, and file005.txt. The directory paths are for my computer so you'll have to make the necessary changes for this to work on your computer.

```
#!python2

import os.path

# directory path to files for name change
source = r'P:\python\stackoverflow\source_files'

# string that will be concatenated to file name
add_date = '20180406'

# make a list of the files and print them
get_files = os.listdir(source)
print get_files, '\n\n'

# change the file names
for item in get_files:
    os.rename(source + '\\' + item, source + '\\' + '20180406_' + item)

# get the files and print their new names
get_files = os.listdir(source)
print get_files
# %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %
```

As a bonus here's how you change the file name extensions.

```
# directory path to files for name change
source = r'P:\python\stackoverflow\source_files'

# make a list of the files and print them
get_files = os.listdir(source)
print get_files, '\n\n'

# change the file name extensions from .txt to .dat
for item in get_files:
    os.rename(source + '\\' + item, source + '\\' + item[0: -3] + 'dat')

# get the files and print their new names
get_files = os.listdir(source)
print get_files
```